# How can I just initialize the thread pool to use it later?

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool

In my application, I am working on asynchronous task processing. For this I am using LinkedBlocking Queue.

Client application will add the Task in this queue. In order to read and process the task, I have created the Listener class.
Earlier in my Listener class, with the help of thread pool I was starting 100 threads which will keep reading and processing data from this queue, since the request load will be much higher. But flaw of this system is 100 threads will always be running and listening to the queue from server start up and will eat up the CPU.

As a solution for this, with the thread pool, I decided to create only 2 threads which will keep listening the queue. There will be a separate thread pool of worker threads which will actually process the task. So these two listener thread will just read the task from queue and will hand over to the worker thread and resume listening.

For example: At server start up, I will create two thread pools. One with size 2 for ‘listener threads’ and other with size 100 for worker threads. 2 Listening threads will be started at server start up and as soon as any Task is added in a queue, any one listener thread will take the task from queue and it will take one thread from worker thread pool and will hand over the task for processing.
Currently I do not know how to initialise the worker thread pool at server start up and how to use thread from it when needed.

Please help me if anyone has any idea about it.
My Listener Class:

```
public class TaskListener implements Runnable{
private int listenerThreadPoolSize = 2;
    private int activeListenerThreads = 2;
    private int WorkerThreadPoolSize = 100;

    public void init(){
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(listenerThreadPoolSize);
        for(int i=1; i<=activeListenerThreads; i++){
            executor.execute(new TaskListener());
        }
        TODO: initialise cache thread pool for worker thread
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Listening to queue");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                Task task = TaskHelper.INSTANCE.getTaskFromQueue();
                System.out.println("processing task. Thread name: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());

                TODO: get thread from worker threadpool and handover the task to worker thread
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem have you encountered here ? How about creating a static field `workersThreadPool`. If your `Task` implements `runnable` you can just add `workersThreadPool.execute(task)` in place of the second `TODO`

Comment: The 100 threads should be blocked when there is no work in the queue, and 100 blocked threads are not 'always running' and do not 'eat up the CPU'. There is no problem here to solve.

Comment: @JanOsch Thank you for your solution. Actually I was a bit confused about thread pool initialization syntax. As per your solution, at 1st TODO I just initialized the thread pool as 
   `'workerThreadsExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(100, Integer.MAX_VALUE,60L,TimeUnit.SECONDS,new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());'`
And in 2nd TODO I used the thread from the pool as `workersThreadPool.execute(task)`

Comment: @JanOsch Earlier my Task interface was not extending runnable, instead it was having its own process method. But by extending Runnable it became easier.
Though I had used thrad pool earlier, I was unaware that the above one line code in first TODO is enough for the thread pool initialization. Thank you :)

Comment: @EJP, Thank you for your reply. I am not sure about the best approach among these two. I just thought that instead of starting 100 threads at server startup and keep them listening the queue forever, it will be better to start only 2-3 threads at server start up which wont perform the task by themselves but only handover the task to a worker thread from a pool. Which approach would be better in your opinion?